# MS Word Interop - access CentimetersToPoints method

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, office-interop, word-2010

I am trying to set the print margins in a Word Doc I am printing from my c# application but I am having trouble accessing the methods that I need to call (based on what they are in MS Word VBA)

In VBA the code looks like this:

```
Options.printBackground = False

With ActiveDocument.PageSetup
    .TopMargin = CentimetersToPoints(0.61)
    .BottomMargin = CentimetersToPoints(0.43)
    .LeftMargin = CentimetersToPoints(1.27)
    .RightMargin = CentimetersToPoints(0.43)
    .Gutter = CentimetersToPoints(0)
End With
```

Here is my c# code

```
oWordDoc.PageSetup.TopMargin = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application.CentimetersToPoints(float.Parse ("0.61"))  ;
```

The error I am getting is:
 `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application.CentimetersToPoints(float)'`

I have tried several varaiations after searching the VS 2010 Object Browser for *CentimetersToPoints*

The available interfaces in the Object Browser are:

- Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application.CentimetersToPoints(float)
- Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass.CentimetersToPoints(float)
- Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Global.CentimetersToPoints(float)
- Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.GlobalClass.CentimetersToPoints(float)

how can I access methods like this?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message indicates, you need a reference to the `Word.Application` object to access this method, since it is not *static*.

I guess you have a `oWordApp` somewhere that you use to create or open the `oWordDoc`, so you can access the method from this object.

Or you can retreive the instance of the `Word.Application` from your `oWordDoc` `(Word.Document`) object.

```
oWordDoc.PageSetup.TopMargin = oWordDoc.Application.CentimetersToPoints(float.Parse("0.61"));
```